# Spring Aop Dependencies

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

**NOTE:** Please ignore if I ask any kind of stupid questions. Apologies in advance.

**PROBLEM:** I am new to spring and spring-aop. Everything was going great untill ***@Aspect*** annotation is used in java class and ***aop:aspectj-autoproxy*** in spring.xml

I have included following jars in runtime classpath:

- aspectjrt.jar
- aspectjweaver.jar
- cglib.jar
- asm.jar
- aopalliance.jar

Now i am facing an issue of ***NoClassDefFoundError*** for ***org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around.class*** although this class exist in ***aspectjrt.jar***

**NOTE:** *I am using Spring-4.1*

**QUESTION:** What are the jars that are required for Spring-AOP? If I have all the jars (as far as i have searched, i have all the jars that are required), then is there any version compatibility issue.

Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Even I'm facing the similar issue. Were you able to fix this problem? If so, kindly add your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add spring-aop? The easiest way would be to use maven for building (or similar dependency management tool) and add dependency to spring-aop
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop/4.1.0.RELEASE

Comment: spring-aop is included in spring-framework-release-4.1, Yes its included.

Answer (score 0):

As of Spring 3.2, it is no longer necessary to add CGLIB to your project classpath, so when using Spring-4.1 you can ignore it

the only jar you need to work Aop on spring project is is aspectjweaver, 
version 1.6.8 or later This library is available in the 'lib' directory of an AspectJ distribution or via the Maven Central repository.=> [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.13)